# Cucumber/Aruba Thor: testing multiple commands in a single scenario, first passes and second fails

Tags: ruby, cucumber, thor, aruba

I'm trying to write a small ruby gem that does some template generating, using Bundler and Thor.  I'm writing the tests in Cucumber and Aruba, and I'm having trouble getting them to pass.

I have the following Thor CLI class defined in the app:

```
require 'thor'
require 'sleipnir'
require 'sleipnir/generators/layout'
require 'sleipnir/generators/app'

module Sleipnir
  class CLI < Thor

    desc "app", "Generates an app directory and copies the appropriate files"
    def app(app_name)
      Sleipnir::Generators::App.start([app_name])
    end

    desc "layout", "Generates specific layout based on template type"
    def layout(template_type)
      Sleipnir::Generators::Layout.start([template_type])
    end
  end
end
```

This is the `app.rb` file:

```
require 'thor/group'

module Sleipnir
  module Generators
    class App < Thor::Group
      include Thor::Actions

      argument :app_name, :type => :string
      class_option :template_type, :default => :erb, :required => true

      def self.source_root
        File.dirname(__FILE__)
      end

      def create_app_dir
        empty_directory(app_name)
      end

      def copy_app_scaffold
        directory("app", app_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the `layout.rb` file:

```
require 'thor/group'

module Sleipnir
  module Generators
    class Layout < Thor::Group
      include Thor::Actions

      class_option :template_type, :default => :erb, :required => true

      def self.source_root
        File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/template"
      end

      def copy_layout
        template_type = options[:template_type]
        template("layout_template.#{template_type}", "views/layout.#{template_type}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have a cucumber test written for the `app` method, and it passes.  However, the `layout` method is failing.  Here is the test:

```
Feature: Generate
  In order to generate templates
  As a CLI
  I want to run the generator

  Scenario: Layout
    When I run `sleipnir app test_app`
    Then the following directories should exist:
      | test_app/views |
    When I run `sleipnir layout --template_type "erb"`
    Then the following files should exist:
      | test_app/views/layout.erb |
```

The first part of the test passes just fine (i.e. the directory is created), but the part about verifying the file exists fails.  I've checked the file structure, and the `layout_template.erb` file exists, so I can't figure out why it isn't be templated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Aruba does not support this: https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/issues/140.

But writing your own step definition isn't bad, just have that you want to execute first happen before the command you pass in. See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Definitions for examples.